# INDEX/MATCH Multiple Criteria Between Dates

Tags: excel

Hope you can help me

My expected result is in column I, 
where if the activity of this specific ID falls into the date range from columns C-D, i will get the minimum date and get the name column

however, in the formula i created, it always get the minimum date for that specific ID and its corresponding name

Not sure how to update the formula, to get the outcome that i need
Appreciate any help!

Thanks

[excel sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJuoG.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Put the dates in a single ordered column if you can:

```
  | A          | B
1 | 2016-01-01 | able
2 | 2016-04-01 | baker
3 | 2016-07-01 | charlie
4 | 2016-10-01 | dog
5 | 2017-01-01 | easy
```

Then if you can use `Index-Match` like this:

```
  | IN         | =Match(IN1, A:A) | =Index(B:B, Match(IN1, A:A))
1 | 2016-01-01 | 1                | able
2 | 2016-02-01 | 1                | able
3 | 2016-04-01 | 2                | baker
```

If your date ranges have to be in two columns - there's probably a much more complicated way to do this using array formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Array formula:

```
=INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(MIN(IF(($C$2:$C$7=G2)*($D$2:$D$7<=H2),H2-$D$2:$D$7)),IF(($C$2:$C$7=G2)*($D$2:$D$7<=H2),H2-$D$2:$D$7),0))
```

We need to find where the date is closest but less than the criteria.

Being an Array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting Edit mode. If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]